# Runtime.exec trying to load spring beans in jar of your project from you .war?

Tags: java, spring, maven-3, runtime.exec

I would like to launch some external java class or jar from my project. But i'd like to use the Bo class from my web app project. I'd like to load them in my main class but i get some weird error.

I run a clean install to get a .war and a .jar with maven. Until that everything works fine.

To get the .jar with dependencies i use :

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.clb.genomic.lyon.external.MainExternal</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Inside my war, i have a bean who makes a call via Runtime.getRuntime.exec to a main class.

```
    public void throwAnalyse(){

    System.out.println("->I call my function");

    try {

    String[] command= {"java","-jar", "/Users/JP/git/CleanOmicsTracer/target/CleanOmicsTracer-jar-with-dependencies.jar"};

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    //test for remote command
    String line;
    BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            bri.close();

            while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            bre.close();

     p.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {  e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }


    System.out.println("End of programme");
}
```

My main class :

```
public class MainExternal {


public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception{


         ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "classpath:webConfiguration/applicationContext.xml");
         ProjectBo projectBo                     = (ProjectBo) appContext.getBean("projectBo");

         System.out.println("-> Im 'in ");

        /************* PRINT OUT  *************/

        Project project = projectBo.findByNameOfStudy("Profiler");

        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) projectBo.findUsers(project);

        for (User myUser : listUser) {

            System.out.println("User :"+myUser.getFirstname());


        }
    }
```

This is the error i get ...

```
    ->I call my function
17:33:37,307  INFO ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7a982589: startup date [Tue Apr 22 17:33:37 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
17:33:37,366  INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [webConfiguration/applicationContext.xml]
17:33:38,296  INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [database/DataSource.xml]
17:33:38,902  INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [database/Hibernate.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/database/Hibernate.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [webConfiguration/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [database/Hibernate.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.clb.genomic.lyon.external.MainExternal.main(MainExternal.java:32)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: class path resource [database/Hibernate.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:240)
    ... 20 more
End of programme
```

Comment: Why do you seperate some code in that jar?

Comment: what do you mean ? It's the same code that the war in fact but i will execute/compile only a certain main class to launnch background job( mailing, parse big files) it's the only way i found to execute some method using the spring beans from a RunTime.exec().

Comment: Don't call runtime.exec() at all. Use a thread to execute concurrent tasks.

Comment: have you a more detailed example ?

Comment: @Stefoan : The process i launch will last at leat two hours. So in the case of a thread, i think that when you close your web app(or maybe the browser, or just Tomcat,really don't know) the thread is shut down because of its linkage to the main process : the webapp ? Is that true or not at all ?