# maven-shade-plugin : make a jar whereas we are in war Project?

Tags: java, maven-3, war, executable-jar, maven-shade-plugin

Question is in the title.
I sucess to first to do a jar (project packaging jar)....then i move it before id do

> mvn clean

to keep it elsewhere.

Or i'm a in a war project so  i have to rename project packaging to war then i have to do a

> mvn clean install

I got my war. I then import the first jar to use from my war.

Is there a clearer way do that with maven shade plugin to generate both war and jar.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
             <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>${project.artifactId}-final</finalName>

              <transformers>
                    <transformer  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.clb.genomic.lyon.external.MainExternal</mainClass>
                   </transformer>
                   <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                         <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                     </transformer>
                     <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                           <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                     </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                  </transformer>
              </transformers>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

The packaging follow

> war/jar

in project description at the begining of the file and i have to change it each time i throw maven.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you want to add some of your code to a jar and add it to the war afterwards?

Comment: I'm trying to execute my jar with beans from spring with Runtime.exec http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223909/runtime-exec-trying-to-load-spring-beans-in-jar-of-your-project-from-you-war . It's working when i use my 2 steps method but it's a bit cumbersome. I'd like the jar with packaging dependencies be generated from only a mvn clean install at the same time that the war is created and then i call it from RunTime.exec() in my web app to do some background process( mailing , parse big files)...

Answer (score 0):

for me you're trying to build two products (a jar and a war) in the same maven module. 
I don't really understand your requirement to have this in the same module? and why are you using maven shade plugin ?

Here is the way I would follow to first make a jar and second make a war that is using the previously just generated jar:

- a parent module (packaging "pom") that defines 2 modules : module_myjar and module_mywar

  - a child module module_myjar (packaging "jar")
  - a child submodule module_mywar (packaging "war") this module could includes jar as dependency.